# PostGIS GeoJSON not displaying in QGIS

Tags: postgis, geojson

I have loaded the following GeoJSON into PostGIS using Java and the table is there but the line will not display. If I zoom to feature it correctly shows the extent, it just doesn't draw it. I've created a spatial index also. Any ideas?

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[360563.95,176361.8627],[360608.6526,176321.6237]]},"properties":{"name":"Canada","classification":1,"height":20.5},"id":"fid.1"}
```

I ran this to load it:

```
                            try {
                                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ogr2ogr -f \"PostgreSQL\" PG:\"dbname=design user=postgres\" \"C:/Users/ajsmi/Dropbox/Consultants/Design/Bristol/Data/Created Data/access.json\"");

                                p.waitFor();
                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        p.getInputStream()));
                                String pline;
                                while ((pline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    System.out.println(pline);

                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            String query = "CREATE INDEX accessspx ON access USING GIST ( wkb_geometry );";
                            try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {

                               pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: GeoJSON is CRS:84, with units of decimal degrees, but looks like your units are metres

Comment: How did you load the data into postgis exactly? what is your table structure?